# How to create this image using CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

[image: How to create this image using CSS?]

I need to be able to replace the image and keep the text/circle. This will be on a responsive site so it needs to work accordingly. (*on bootstrap 3 platform.)

Here's what I got so far:

```css
.box {
 color:#fff;
 height:auto;
 position:relative; 
 z-index:0;
 overflow:hidden;
  max-width:586px;
 }
 .box:after {
 content:'yarn';
 display:block;
 height: 160px;
 width:160px;
 background-color:red;
 border-radius:50%;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:-10px;
 left:40%;
 z-index:-1;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://siterepository.s3.amazonaws.com/4253/yarn.jpg" alt="" width="586" height="362" align="" /></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the `border-radius` just for the `top right` and `top left` corners using:

```
 border-top-left-radius: 80px; 
 border-top-right-radius: 80px;
```

**Note:** I used `80px` not `50%`, as `80px` is half of the `160px` width

Then give the circle half the `height` than the `width`. (80px, 160px)

After that I set the `z-index:1;` to be higher than `-1` so you could see the circle.

Use `text-align:center;` to center the text.

I also replaced `left:40%` with `left: calc((100% - 160px)/2);` which will give you the exact center. (the whole width minus the width of the circle divided by 2)

Add `line-height: 80px;` to center the text vertically in the half circle

```css
.box {
 color:#fff;
 height:auto;
 position:relative; 
 z-index:0;
 overflow:hidden;
  max-width:586px;
 }
 .box:after {
 content:'Yarn';
 display:block;
 height: 80px;
 width:160px;
 background-color:red;
 border-top-left-radius: 80px; 
 border-top-right-radius: 80px;
 text-align:center;
 line-height: 80px;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:-10px;
 left:calc((100% - 160px)/2);
 z-index:10;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://siterepository.s3.amazonaws.com/4253/yarn.jpg" alt="" width="586" height="362" align="" /></div>
```